# Insert on duplicate keys In java

Tags: java, sql

I have this program that  I wrote and i'm having a problem. I started this project using "insert" only without "On duplicate keys" and it  worked fine. now since i added it, the code goes into an loop and does not execute anything. I have this code reading from a file and inserts into a database. I tried update but it does not work if there is a  new item in that file. Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong.

here is my Code

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;

 public class mysql {
static Connection conn;
public static void main (String argv[]) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException     {
File file = new File("/home/bandoc/data.txt");

if (!file.exists()) {
    System.out.println("Cannot Read File\n");
}
BufferedReader br = null;
//connect to mysql db
Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://localhost/membership?  user=My-Username&password=my-Password");
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet mysqldata = stmt.executeQuery ("select * from logIn");

try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file.getPath()));    
}catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = "";
try {
    line = br.readLine();

}
catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

PreparedStatement stm =  conn.prepareStatement("insert into logIn (logId, logFname, logLname, logDept, logUser, logEmail, logDeptCode) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE test =1");

while (line != null) {
    if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("ID:")) {
        try {
            line = br.readLine();

            stm.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(line.toString()));
            line = br.readLine();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (line.equalsIgnoreCase( "First:")) {
        try {
            line = br.readLine();

            stm.setString(2,line);
            line = br.readLine();
         }catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                     }

    }
    if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("Last:")) {
        try {
            line = br.readLine();

            stm.setString(3,line);
            line = br.readLine();
         }catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                     }

    }
    if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("Dept:")) {
        try {
                        line = br.readLine();

                        stm.setString(4,line);
                        line = br.readLine();
         }catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                     }


    if (line.equalsIgnoreCase( "User:")) {
                    try {
                            line = br.readLine();

                            stm.setString(5,line);
                            line = br.readLine();
                     }catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                     }
        }

    if (line.equalsIgnoreCase( "Email:")) {
                    try {
                            line = br.readLine();

                            stm.setString(6,line);
                            line = br.readLine();
                     }catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                     }
        }


    if (line.equalsIgnoreCase( "Deptcode:")) {
                    try {
                            line = br.readLine();

                            stm.setString(7,line);
                            //line = br.readLine();
                     }catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                     }

        }   


    }
    stm.execute();
}
 try {
            br.close();
    }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }



    System.out.println("done");

}
  }
```

Comment: _does not work_ Are you getting an SQLException? If so, which one?

Comment: `on duplicate key update test` doesn't appear to make sense, what is `test` supposed to be? There is no such column in your table.

Comment: the code compiles and runs but just runs forever and does not do anything. Test is just a column i added and its value is not important.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code execution, see if ever gets to the `stmt.execute()`?  Also, because you are doing an upsert (which is an update), you should probably change your call to `executeUpdate()` instead.  Not saying that's causing your issue, but you know it's an update so call the method related to performing an update.

Comment: first thing i always say to people is separate SQL from the actual code. do SQL connect class and rest of classes separate

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are never getting out of your while loop.  You read the first line and then go into a loop that stops when the line read in is `null`. You have a bunch of conditions in the loop to check the line and read another line if it matches some condition.  So, if the first line read is not `null`, and that first line matches no condition in your loop, you will be stuck in that loop forever.  A little debugging will prove (or disprove this), as might a final `else` condition at the bottom to log that you hit an unexpected line (and print it) and then go ahead and read the next line.

Answer (score 0):

If your 'line' does not equal one of the conditions e.g. 'ID:', then the next readline is not done and 'line' remains the same, hence a never ending loop